# 'Failed to refresh tokens: Missing required parameter auth parameters.' - AWS Amplify Pull API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am building a VueJS App using AWS Amplify where I build the backend in the Admin UI, which is great and easy.

I added the Auth in my App through the command line, but I am building all the models through the AdminUI. Yesterday it was working great, I was doing amplify pull --appId XXXX --envName staging and it was pulling my latest models etc etc...
but this morning, I get:

**⠏ Fetching updates to backend environment: staging from the cloud.Failed to refresh tokens: Missing required parameter auth parameters.
Failed to get credentials: Missing required parameter auth parameters.**

Whenever I am performing the pull.

Comment: I have just added Auth to my app using Admin UI and I am as stuck as you are, have you found anything?

Comment: Apparently it is a new bug... you need to do:

amplify logout --appID XXXX

Answer (score 9):

This is a new bug by AWS... you need to do:

amplify logout --appID XXXXX

Comment: Retrying to `amplify push` will ask you to reconfigure authentication. I was successfully able to run it afterwords. Thanks.